# Dante SOCKS server with two external interfaces (e.g. Wired Ethernet and Wi-Fi)

Tags: proxy, ifconfig, socks, dante

I want Dante to transparently choose between either of the two interfaces `enp4s0` (Wired Ethernet) and `wlp3s0` (Wi-Fi) regardless of their status (up or down).  That is

- when wired, it should choose `enp4s0` indeed,
- when `wlp3s0` is added, it should preferably stay on `enp4s0` (or maybe do some other clever stuff, I care less about this point here),
- when wire (`enp4s0`) is down, i.e. I'm traveling, it should of course switch to `wlp3s0` as the only option left.

Now I was under impression that the following configuration should do the trick:

```
internal: 0.0.0.0 port=1080
external: enp4s0
external: wlp3s0
external.rotation: route
```

However, to my surprise, when e.g. only `enp4s0` is up and `wlp3s0` is down, Dante refuses to start up, barking:

```
error: /etc/sockd.conf: problem on line ??? near token "wlp3s0": could not resolve hostname "wlp3s0": No address associated with hostname.  Please see the Dante manual for more information
```

I do understand the point here, but there is no technical reason behind such limitation.  Manually editing this configuration file every time I'm switching between wire and Wi-Fi would be cumbersome and a big no-no.  Is there a clever way to address that issue?

As the last resort, maybe some hook script that would modify the configuration file?  Examples of such tools/scripts?

Comment: Looks like `NetworkManager` dispatcher service could be of use here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the time being, I went with [`goproxy`](https://github.com/snail007/goproxy), what a gem!  Essentially,

```
$ goproxy socks -t tcp -p '0.0.0.0:1080'
```

does the trick without any hassle about binding any particular outgoing interfaces.

---

I got the following response from Michael Shuldman (maintainer) on the official mailing list for Dante server `sockd`:

> Perhaps there is no technical reason, but in a normal production
> setting (i.e., as used at a company), specifying that Dante should use
> a non-existing/non-configured NIC (network interface card) would
> normally indicate a configuration error.  E.g., a sockd.conf copied
> from another server with different NIC-names, or an OS upgrade causing
> renaming of some NIC's.
>
> It was therefor thought to be best to error out immediately, to make
> sure the admin will notice and fix the problem at once, as it's not
> expected behaviour in the settings our customers use Dante.
>
> For more personal, rather than business usage, some more thought
> should probably be given to scenarios such as yours, but that has
> unfortunately not been prioritized.
>
> One future alternative might be to rather than error out, just print a
> warning and continue as long as there is at least one operable NIC
> configured in sockd.conf.  That's probably something that could be
> implemented fairly easy without much risk of causing other problems,
> so I think I'll add a note for that to be looked into for a later
> release.
>
> A 1.4.3-maintainance release is already under testing, so I don't
> think anything can be added to it at this point unfortunately, but
> perhaps for 1.5.0 someone will have a look.